# Select columns that present a specific condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter, mask, any

I have a dataframe relating species and sites. Each cell contains a abundance value. I want to select only those species that present an abundance higher than 5 in any site.

Input:

```
#df
        Species_1 Species_2 Species_3
    Site_1 0 0 1
    Site_2 0 0 0
    Site_3 6 0 7
```

Desirable output:

```
    Species_1 Species3
Site_1 0 1
Site_2 0 0
Site_3 6 7
```

Imagine that I have a dataframe 150 x 150, and I want to select objetively each column withou writing their names.
I managed to write a mask for the dataframe (eg. mask = df > 5), but I do not know how to select only those columns that present at least one "True" value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Species_1': {'Site_1': 0, 'Site_2': 0, 'Site_3': 6}, 'Species_2': {'Site_1': 0, 'Site_2': 0, 'Site_3': 0}, 'Species_3': {'Site_1': 1, 'Site_2': 0, 'Site_3': 7}, 'Species_4': {'Site_1': 2, 'Site_2': 2, 'Site_3': 2}})
#        Species_1  Species_2  Species_3  Species_4
#Site_1          0          0          1          2
#Site_2          0          0          0          2
#Site_3          6          0          7          2

df.loc[:, (df > 5).any()]
#        Species_1  Species_3
#Site_1          0          1
#Site_2          0          0
#Site_3          6          7
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using this:

```
df.loc[:, df.gt(5).any()]
```

output:

```
    Species_1   Species_3
Site_1  0   1
Site_2  0   0
Site_3  6   7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a datframe where species_2 does not occur >5 at any site even though its sum is greater than 5 at all sites:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Species_1': {'Site_1': 0, 'Site_2': 0, 'Site_3': 6},
                   'Species_2': {'Site_1': 3, 'Site_2': 2, 'Site_3': 1},
                   'Species_3': {'Site_1': 1, 'Site_2': 0, 'Site_3': 7}})
print(df)
#
        Species_1  Species_2  Species_3
Site_1          0          3          1
Site_2          0          2          0
Site_3          6          1          7
```

Here is how you return only Species_1 and Species_3:

```
df = df[df > 5]
df.dropna(axis=1, how= "all", inplace=True)
print(df.columns.to_list())

#['Species_1', 'Species_3']
```